# Detect overflown rows in a table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table a of an arbitrary height. The rows are dynamically populated by javascript. I don't want the table exceed its height when new rows are being added. New rows are added at the top of the table and old rows should be removed from the bottom of the table.

Is there a way to detect if a row has overflown?

For illustration rows **f, g, h, i** should be removed.

[image]

```css
.cnt {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 50vh;
    max-width: 100vw;
    max-height: 50vh;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
section {
  height: 100%
}
table {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;  
  overflow: hidden;
}
table tbody tr td{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="cnt">
      <section>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr><td>a</td></tr>
            <tr><td>b</td></tr>
            <tr><td>c</td></tr>
            <tr><td>d</td></tr>
            <tr><td>e</td></tr>
            <tr><td>f</td></tr>
            <tr><td>g</td></tr>
            <tr><td>i</td></tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </section>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can try this- .table ,.table tbody>tr>td{
    table-layout:fixed;     
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;  
}

Answer (score 1):

When you add a row, count every time the summary height of all the rows, and delete redundant rows.

```js
clear();

function clear() {
  const table = document.querySelector('table');
  let sum = 0;
  let i = 0;
  while (i < table.rows.length) {
    let h = table.rows[i].clientHeight;
    if (sum + h > table.clientHeight) {
      table.deleteRow(i);
    } else {
      sum += h;
      i++;
    } 
  }
}
```

```css
.cnt {
  height: 50vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

section {
  height: 100%;
}

table {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="cnt">
      <section>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr><td>a</td></tr>
            <tr><td>b</td></tr>
            <tr><td>c</td></tr>
            <tr><td>d</td></tr>
            <tr><td>e</td></tr>
            <tr><td>f</td></tr>
            <tr><td>g</td></tr>
            <tr><td>i</td></tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </section>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```